# Find View that is the firstresponder

Tags: iphone, ios, first-responder

I would like to get the view that is the first responder, currently I have a UITableView that contains UITextFields, using a method:

```
-(UIView*) findFirstResponder
{

}
```

I would like to be able to get the view that is the firstResponder and then do something with that view.

Any ideas?

Comment: How many textFields you have in tableView?

Comment: They are dynamically created but I found a way just now

Comment: I recommend to sway away from the for loop approach if at all possible, which could add unnecessary processing. A cleaner approach we be to create a variable, local or instance, to hold a reference to the active object, usually set in a delegate method, such as the `UITextFieldDelegate` method - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField.

Comment: It seems to me that the easiest way to achieve this is to call `UIView* responderView = [[self window] firstResponder];` and then: `if ([responderView isKindOf:[UITextField class]]) { /*do the magic*/ }`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All I had to do was

```
@implementation UIView (FindViewThatIsFirstResponder)
- (UIView *)findViewThatIsFirstResponder
{
    if (self.isFirstResponder) {        
        return self;     
    }

    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        UIView *firstResponder = [subView findViewThatIsFirstResponder];
        if (firstResponder != nil) {
            return firstResponder;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
@end
```

Comment: Don't you need the textField itself? What is the relation between the subview and the table with the textFields?

Comment: To go into more detail of why this will work for me: I have a UITextField that has a UIPickerView as a inputView, now these are all created dynamically so I don't hold any reference to any fields except my table view, so when I select a textfield the UIPickerView will show up and I then select a value in the picker to set the text of the UITextField, I then had to call a delegate method to pass the selected value back to the current firstresponder. see this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874037/uipickerview-and-uitextfield-get-value-from-uipickerview/

Answer (score 14):

Use UIControl as a root reference to different types of control that can become first responder.

```
UIControl *currentControl;
```

As Gobot says - whenever a textfield becomes first responder, keep a note of which one it is...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {   

    currentControl = textField;

    . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to find `firstResponder` in iOS. The answers above are only tracking `UIView`s but all subclasses of `UIResponder` such as `UIViewController` can be a first responder.

According to the `Quick Help` of `UIResponder`:

> Many key objects are also responders, including the UIApplication
> object, UIViewController objects, and all UIView objects (which
> includes UIWindow). As events occur, UIKit dispatches them to your
> app's responder objects for handling.

And the only way to follow `UIResponder` chain will be using `UIResponder`'s `next: UIResponder` property.

> Returns the next responder in the responder chain, or nil if there is
> no next responder. The UIResponder class does not store or set the
> next responder automatically, so this method returns nil by default.
> Subclasses must override this method and return an appropriate next
> responder. For example, UIView implements this method and returns the
> UIViewController object that manages it (if it has one) or its
> superview (if it doesn’t). UIViewController similarly implements the
> method and returns its view’s superview. UIWindow returns the
> application object. UIApplication returns nil.

In the most `UIKit` object `superview`, `UIViewController`, `UIWindow`, `UIApplication` or `Appdelegate` will be the `next` `UIResponder`.

```
extension UIResponder {
    func findFirstResponder() -> UIResponder? {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            guard let r = responder, r.isFirstResponder else {
                responder = responder?.next
                continue
            }
            return r
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

However the above doesn't track `responder`'s siblings. I guess if you really want to track them all, you need to check the type of responder and track its child(subview, child view controller).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to shared with you my implementation for find first responder in anywhere of UIView. I hope it helps and sorry for my english. Thanks

```
+ (UIView *) findFirstResponder:(UIView *) _view {
   if ([subView isFirstResponder])
      return subView;
   if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
      UIView *v = subView;

      if ([v.subviews count] > 0) {
         retorno = [self findFirstResponder:v];
         if ([retorno isFirstResponder]) {
             return retorno;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of the fact that calling `UIApplication.shared.sendAction` with a target of `nil` sends the action to the first responder.

### Swift

```swift
extension UIResponder {
    
    private static weak var _firstResponder: UIResponder?
    
    static var firstResponder: UIResponder? {
        _firstResponder = nil
        // Tell the first responder to record itself in `_firstResponder`
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(_recordFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        return _firstResponder
    }
    
    @objc private func _recordFirstResponder() {
        UIResponder._firstResponder = self
    }
    
}
```

Then simply accessing `UIResponder.firstReponder` will give us the first responder.

### Objective-C

```objectivec
static __weak id foundFirstResponder;

@implementation UIResponder (FindFirstResponder)

+(id)firstResponder {
    foundFirstResponder = nil;
    [UIApplication.sharedApplication sendAction:@selector(findFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
    return foundFirstResponder;
}

-(void)findFirstResponder {
    foundFirstResponder = self;
}
@end
```